# AFNetworking Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager"

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have tried everything i have found in other questions similar to this.

**This is what I have imported:**

SystemConfiguration

MobileCoreServices

Security

CoreGraphics

UIKit

Foundation

I've only added to my project the "AFNetworking" folder that is inside "AFNetworking-2.4.0".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all files in this directory:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache

After remove files,restart Xcode.

This might be a solution. (To jump the directory, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in the Finder and paste the path above)

Comment: Did you try CocoaPods? http://cocoapods.org @LucasLourenço A great dependency manager.

Comment: @zeveisenberg I found this tip trying to troubleshoot AFNetworking migration from 2 > 3 and after reading the answer I thought. Good idea. I'll use Zev's eviscerateDerivedData script and that did the trick. Then we I came back to credit the answer I saw your name on the edit. You should share your eviscerate script!